# variable in session name

Tags: php, variables, session-variables

Is it possible to have a variable in a session name?
Like if I have a variable: `$id`
I want something like this:

```
$_SESSION['number'$id]
```

So that if `$id=1`

```
$_SESSION['number1']
```

And if `$id=65`

```
$_SESSION['number65']
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use an array in this situation?

Answer (score 13):

Yes - you can do this.

All you have to do is **concatenate a string value** as the index in the `$_SESSION` array.

```
$id= 42;
$result = $_SESSION['number'.$id];
```

Now `$result` will be equal to the value of `$_SESSION` at the *index* `"number42"`;

---

The same can be done for any associative array as well.

```
$any_assoc_array = array('index42'=>'Hooray!');
$id= 42;
$result = $any_assoc_array['index'.$id];
echo $result;
```

OUTPUT :

```
 Hooray!
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can place variable names within a string literal if in double-quotes, so the following is perfectly legal. Note that the variable can appear anywhere in the string literal.

```
$result = $_SESSION["number$id"];
```